# Find number of occurrences and positional matches of 2 arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, comparison

I'm struggling with some logic code in C#...
I want to check if an element of one array is in the same position as the element of another array, and if not, if it occurs in the array elsewhere.
Let me show some examples (the letters are short for colors White, Blue, Red, Green):

```
array1: W B G G  
array2: W R G B  
----------------  
2 exact matches: W in position 1 and G in position 3
1 other occurrences: B (position 2 in array1 and position 4 in array2)


array1: W R B B 
array2: R W G G
---------------- 
should return:  
0 exact matches
2 other occurrences:  W (position 1 in array1 and position 2 in array2)
                     R (position 2 in array1 and position 1 in array2)

array1: B W W B 
array2: R W R R
---------------- 
should return:  
1 exact match: W in position 2 
0 other occurrences

array1: G R R B  
array2: R R R B
----------------  
should return:   
3 exact matches: R in position 2 and 3, and B in position 4  
0 other occurrences
```

So to be clear: I only want to know the number of matches and number of occurrences, not the exact positions where the matches are.
Can this be done using LINQ and arrays? Or is there an 'easier' way?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

After a good sleep I found a solution myself :-)

```
// 2 example arrays    
char[] List1 = { 'B', 'W', 'W', 'B' };
char[] List2 = { 'R', 'W', 'B', 'W' };

int BlackPin = 0;
int WhitePin = 0;

// First check all exact matches
for (int i = 0; i < List2.Length; i++)
{
    // check if there is an exact match
    if (List2[i] == List1[i])
    {
        // Black pin, as it is found, and on the exact place
        BlackPin++;
        List1[i] = '!';
        continue;
    }
}

// Now check all non-exact matches
for (int i = 0; i < List2.Length; i++)
{ 
    int Index = Array.IndexOf(List1, List2[i]);
    if (Index == -1)
    {
        // Nothing found, so moving to the next
        continue;
    }
    // White pin, as it is found, but not on the exact place
    List1[Index] = '!';
    WhitePin++;
}

Console.WriteLine($"# exact matches: {BlackPin}");
Console.WriteLine($"# non-exact matches: {WhitePin}");
```

What do you think? Are there simpler ways of doing this?